# the console in pydev no longer reports the errors in my scripts

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using pydev to write some simple scripts. Unfortunately the console stopped displaying the errors in my scripts. Does anybody knows what might be the problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: restart my OS. (I am running CentosOS 6.3).
I felt I was using Windows 10 years ago. Where is the world going !?

Maybe somebody wants to pick up this bug,
unfortunately, I have no logs.

Thanks to the community anyway,